# Jest mock a const

Tags: jestjs

I want to test a js file where it has a reference of a const coming from another import (parser.js)

```
const { cp } = CML
```

How can I mock this and only this and not the rest of functions?. It is throwing this error:

```
ReferenceError: CML is not defined

at Object.<anonymous> (src/state/lib/parser.js:2:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/state/reducers/stateReducer.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/state/reducers/index.js:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/state/store/index.js:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/state/store/store.spec.js:4:1)
```

CML is a var defined in other js resource file.

This is the parser.js file:

```
/* global CML */
const { cp } = CML;

// Massaging approvals array data
// Adding status and trimming unused values
export default {
    approvals: (approvals = [], globalActions = []) => (
        approvals.map(approval => {
            let status = 'default';
            let rejected = false;
            let reviewed = 0;
            ...
```

And in stateReducer class this is the import of the parser:

```
import parser from '../lib/parser';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jest.mock('./state/lib/parser', function() {  // Put the exact path you've imported in your file
  return {
    CML: 123,
  };
});
```

Comment: yes, but then I have another error: TypeError: _parser.default.approvals is not a function. This one, approvals function is the one that I don't want to mock

Comment: It would help if you could share your parser.js and how you're import it in your file.

Comment: parser.js file uploaded